# Docusign embedded sending

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the docusign APIs but I want to create an envelope with a pdf document, I followed the walkthroughs on the docusign site and the example there for embedded sending, sends first an envelope and then it shows me the document that was send, I wanted to do the opposite thing. I want to first upload the document, then review that document and add tags by dragging and dropping them and then click send and send it to the user, you know more similar to how it is done when the console is used. So, how do i do that?

So basically, I want to call the https://na2.docusign.net/Member/EnvelopeSetup.aspx within my own application.

Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use DocuSign's Embedded Sending feature.

[DocuSign REST API - Embedded Sending](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf#page=27)

### Embedded Sending

The embedded sending resource retrieves a url for accessing the tagging and sending page of the 
DocuSign console. The envelope ID used here is the envelope that is opened in the console view.

To open an envelope in the console for embedded sending, the `/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender` uri is appended to the base Url 
value to get the url to open the envelope in the DocuSign console.

After opening the envelope in the console, you can make changes to the envelope and send it.

**Example Request**

```
POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender 



X-DocuSign-Authentication: 
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><Integrato
rKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials> 
Accept: application/json 
Content-Type: application/json 

{ 
 "returnUrl":"https://www.docusign.com" 
}
```

### Response

The response returns the url to access the console.

The following example shows the header followed by the response json body.

**Example Response**

```
201 Created
Content-Length: 168 
Cache-Control: private 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 14:53:16 GMT 

{"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/Member\/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=6cafaeaa-cc6b-
496d-812d-421b72f854de&DocuEnvelope=AB52A90E-BDC7-4F59-BFBD-90E32E984EA7&send=1"}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted but one more question, now I have embedded the sending but can I disable the document button so that users cannot browse files and change the documents? similar to the recipients lock mechanism but with the document.

Also, can I disable the send button so that I can create my own send button?

Thanks a million.